# windows 8.1 crashes during game play? How do i find out whats causing it?

Tags: crash, logging

I just bought a near new gaming desktop. I7 3770, gtx 970 8gb ram so on. It was technically second hand. The computer runs fine for movies, internet and basic games. Everytime i play watchdogs on ultra 1080p it crashes right when i get to what looks like the most graghics intense outside world 10 min in. The fan goes really loud the after ten seconds it just reboots with no blue screen. In bf4 ultra 1080p it only ever lets me get a couple of minutes in the the fans go loud and screen dies but fans continue till i maually turn off pc. I tried reloading my own win 8.1 and redoing games with same results. Fans are running and temps were staying stable at ok temps. I ran passmark benchmark test for 10 min and it gave great appropriate scores with no problems. Is there a way to find logs or something to show whats failing/happening?

I know this rig should run these games at ultra as my old gtx 670 can too. Worried of cos. Any help finding logs or solution would be much appreciated. Hope this is the right site i was bought here about another win 8 looking for logs post but his had blue screen. Thanks

Comment: obligatory:  are all your drivers, specifically nvidia drivers up to date?

Comment: Yeah got all the latest gigabyte (motherboard) , intel drivers and the latest 970 drivers straight from nvidia

Comment: Check your `Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application` and look for anything with a yellow or red icon. If the application is your game or nVidia driver then look into the error code it has given you. I recently had Rocketdock.exe crap out with an exception code of 0xc0000409. There might be a good reason why someone was trying to get rid of such a new rig with beast specs.

Comment: Why do you have Intel display drivers installed of you have a Nvidia gpu?

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to find out what causes this?

Basically what happens is that a Blue Screen of Death happens, and windows reboots after it. In your case, it happens so quickly that you do not see the BSoD happening, but it happens.

## Finding out the problem

Now the first thing to do is looking into the info provided by the BSoD.

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Administrative tools
3. Event Viewer
4. Unvold Windows Logs
5. Click on `System`
6. On the right, click `Filter current log...`
7. Check Critical and Error
8. Click where it says `<All Event IDs>`
9. Enter 1001
10. Press OK.

This will show you all events where a BSoD happened.

Click on an item. The message will say `The bugcheck was: 0x?????????????`

Write down this nummer. You can ommit any 0 except the one before the x. So 0x000000000116 becomes 0x116. *Note: if you have a number on the left of the 0, you cannot ommit it: for example: 0x0000010005 = 0x10005 or 0xc00000001f = 0xc00000001f*

Google for BSoD 0x116 (or what your BSoD code is) to find out what happened.

## More detailed info about the BSoD

There are advanced tools to actually dive into a minidump.dmp or memory.dmp and retrace the steps of windows, but even I struggle with this. So the best next thing is a little tool by NirSoft called [Blue Screen View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), which allows you to directly open the minidump or memorydump and get information about the BSoD and which driver caused it. But you usually do not need to go this far.